# Trigger a click on a specific tab loaded inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

I'm just trying to trigger a click on a particular tab using JS/jQuery. I'm having a web page which contains a iframe & which has number of tabs, loading page using ajax.

I'm able to find the specific tab:

```
$('#decider').find('iframe').contents().find('[data-tab="lay_customblock"] a').length;
```

And, also can able to give css color for that tab:

```
$('#decider').find('iframe').contents().find('[data-tab="lay_customblock"] a').css('color','#900')
```

But my issue is that, I was not able to trigger a click on that tab, i have tried:

```
$('#decider').find('iframe').contents().find('[data-tab="lay_customblock"] a').trigger('click');
```

I have check all this in code & also using browser console.

Comment: Can you show us your `click` handler? And where did you declare it ? Inside your `iframe` or inside your page?

Comment: Its all in a JS page which is loaded with the web page not with in iframe.

Comment: does the iframe load from the same domain? if not, it's a `Same Origin Policy` problem

Comment: Yes its on same domain.

Comment: @Sinto Does the `click` handler trigger when you manually click on it ?

Comment: yes. that's why I'm confused.

Comment: does it get alerted when you do `$('#decider')
    .find('iframe')
    .contents()
    .find('[data-tab="lay_customblock"] a')
    .click(function () {
        alert('test');
    });`

Comment: @Sinto Can you share us a working example of your issue?

Comment: @Zenoo: let me try that.

Comment: Did you try `...a')[0].click()`?

Comment: I got a work around for the issue & is almost fixed now. Thank you for your supports.